# Event to track quote changes in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I want an observer to track changes in Quote like when removing products, updating, adding product from frontend and backend as well. This observer should run after magento native code.

There are many events like below which are executed during quote but I am not sure which observer will be fit for my requirement--

**sales_quote_remove_item**

**sales_quote_add_item**

**sales_quote_product_add_after**

**sales_quote_item_collection_products_after_load**

**checkout_cart_add_product_complete**

**checkout_cart_save_before**

**checkout_cart_save_after**
etc...

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to achieve this by using a single event , but instead you could write a single observer and call this observer for multiple events..

```
      <sales_quote_product_add_after>
        <observers>
          <sales_quote_product_add>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>my_module/observer</class>
            <method>myfunction</method>
          </sales_quote_product_add>
        </observers>
      </sales_quote_product_add_after>          


      <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
        <observers>
          <checkout_cart_add_product>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>my_module/observer</class>
            <method>myfunction</method>
          </checkout_cart_add_product>
        </observers>
      </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
```

Events you can see
sales_quote_remove_item
sales_quote_item_qty_set_after
sales_quote_product_add_after

https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/

You can find events on your own
Modify Mage.php in app folder

```
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
$result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);

//log your event
Mage::log("Event name is $name",null,'event.log');

return $result;
}
```

Do your action, like add item to cart, remove / update quantity and then check event.log in var/log